# Device calendar plugin for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

We are using the device_calendar plugin and we are trying to reproduce the example app in ours. Im running into one error that I dont understand. The error is on the "enum DayOfWeekGroup". It is undefined even though I am including the package import. I tried adding it manually from the example code but it exists outside of the example project so its causing issues.

the plugin is :  device_calendar: ^3.0.0+1

The enum exists in  src folder outside the example everything else is being pulled into the package from the import but this enum.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not in the plugin yet, the workaround is use DayOfWeek enum in place of DayOfWeekGroup just in case someone is messing with the new version of device Calendar plugin like I was :)